# how to draw curved Circle arrow by using HTML/svg/D3.js/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I need to create an svg circle where the stroke gradually fades into the background and there's an arrow at one end. What I need now is that right above the arrow the ring should fade in to nothing, exactly like the image attached.[fading ring with arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFpLl.png)

Please suggest the necessary modifications to the code shared in the snippet below so the svg looks exactly like the image

```html
<svg height="210" width="220" transform = 'translate(-10 10)' >
    <linearGradient id="grad1"  x1="0%" y1="40%" x2="20%" y2="-20%">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#3381FF" />
          <!--stop offset= "0%" stop-color= ""/-->
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#3381FF" stop-opacity="0" />
        </linearGradient>      
      <circle cx="100" cy="105" r="96" stroke="url(#grad1)" stroke-width="16" fill="none"  transform='translate(14 0)' />
      <svg height="210" width="500"  transform = 'translate(-10 10)'>
      <!--polygon points="56,101 73,141 66,101 83,141" style="fill:white;stroke:white;stroke-width:1" -->
      <polygon points="19 65 33.5,105 3.5,105" style="fill:#3381FF;stroke:#3381FF;stroke-width:1" />
    </svg>        
    </svg>
```

> Blockquote

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried using Svg path but could not get the exact dimension as needed I have no idea how to draw circle with an arrow sign.I was searching the entire day but no clue .I am just a beginner

Comment: Have you tried to create the SVG manually? E.g. start with a circle, then go for the 75% circle, then add some arrows and finally adjust the arrows to have the right angle

Comment: I don't know how to do that this is what I did so far.drew the half circle but it's showing clockwise and I have no idea how to.show arrow ..  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50,0, 1.75* Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
</script> 

</body>

Comment: Can anyone modify this code and add an arrow sign along with Gradient filled color instead of Solid orange color. https://jsfiddle.net/pw2c1rss/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start with a SVG, path and line elements. Look for the docs how to draw an [arc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths). Here is a quick example:

```html
<svg height="150" width="150">
  <rect height="150" width="150" fill="#EEE" />
  <g> 
    <path
      d="M 75 25
         A 50 50, 0, 1, 1, 25 75"
      stroke="tomato"
      stroke-width="2"
      fill="transparent"
    />

    <line x1="25" y1="75" x2="15" y2="85" stroke="tomato"  stroke-width="2" />
    <line x1="25" y1="75" x2="35" y2="85" stroke="tomato"  stroke-width="2" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I used the `<rect ... />` to provide a grey background, the `<path ... />` to draw the arc, the two `<line ... />` element for the arrowheads.

```
75 start x,
25 start y,
                                  +--- x-end point
                                  |  
        counter clockwise ---+    | +--- y-end endpoint
                             |    | |
<path d="M 75 25 A  50  50 0 1 1 25 75" stroke="red" fill="none"/>
                     |   | |   |
  1 Radius x-Axis ---+   | |   +--- 4 short / long way
                         | |
      2 Radius y-Axis ---+ +--- 3 Rotation x
```